# How to implement EasyStar.js pathfinding logic to my present grid generator

Tags: javascript, html, path-finding

I have this project where I need to visualize 2d grid pathfinding.

I managed to create a grid generator that generates the grid up to 20x20.

I need to install a library that provides a pathfinding algorithm and apply it to my present grid generator. I spend countless hours already but I'm stuck.

What do I expect to get:
I need to have a grid-item 'start' (green) on the left first column and an 'end' grid item on the last column (any row for both) as all the grid items have to be filled (non-walkable) and then as soon as I click the grid item it walkable. When there is a clear path between the start and end it should color accordingly (pretty much pathfinding :D)

Here is the sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-gagarin-v9pce9?file=/src/index.js:229-304

I have already tried various approaches, but the majority of the time as soon as I import the easyst.js

const EasyStar = require("easystarjs");
const easystar = new EasyStar.js();
and trying to loop the grid and etc, everything stops

Comment: Please don't use codesanbox and read [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.